# Is there a standard order of operations for data preparation?

Tags: data, preprocessing

In what order should I do the following given a dataset:

- (E)ncoding of Categorical Variables
- (N)ormalization
- (B)alancing of data
- (I)mputation of Missing Values
- (R)emoval of Duplicates/Infinity/Outliers/Corrupt/Bad values
- (F)eature ranking/selection/engineering

I am aware that it will vary from dataset to dataset, but I'm looking for a heuristic here and some reasoning to better understand why the order of operations would change given some dataset.

I currently do: R -> I -> B -> E -> N -> F

If I've missed something, please let me know. I am a student and I am still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context. Your order of steps is fairly standard.

One option is to treat the order of processing steps as a hyperparameter. Then see if different orders can improve model performance, while making sure the ordering is valid and there is no data leakage.

Comment: That's a super interesting thought, Brian. I never thought about treating the order of operations as a hyperparameter. That's something I'll definitely incorporate into my standard approach.